# Log Analysis...How To

Tags: log

How do I find out information about logs that are in a file on my desktop called "logs," such as what application from which they were created, the sizes of the exports logged, what the most common error is amongst the logs, and other information, as well. I'm fairly new to the command line and Linux and this whole side of web development and design and I am in desperate need of assistance! I thank you so much for taking the time to help me!

LindsayLambo

Comment: Open the logs with any text editor and read them =). I am not aware of any application that would put a log on your desktop, but without additional information , hard to say. Only you know what your are running =)

Answer (score 0):

Read `man 3 syslog` to see how programs send stuff towards the logs, `less /etc/rsyslog.conf /etc/rsyslog.d/*` to see how messages are distributed to log files, and `man rsyslog.conf` to understand the output from the previous command.